# SQLCLR project has build error about 'System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo' not being defined in assembly

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio, sqlclr

I have a SQLCLR project in VS2015, it is set for .NET 4.5.1 and SQL Server 2016. It uses `System.Xml.Linq`.

When I build the project I get errors saying:

> The type 'System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.

and suggests loading `System.Xml 4.0.0`.

When searching I found sites saying that I had to add a reference to `System.Core` as it contains `System.Xml`, so I did it but still get the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: The assembly System.Core does not contain the type System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo. That type is found in the assembly System.Xml. That's the reason Visual Studio suggests you reference System.Xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the references to System.Xml and System.Core, cleaned the solution, closed VS, opened VS, and added System.Xml and System.Core and the error went away. The error still appears in the error list but no longer makes the build fail. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation for [IXmlLineInfo Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.ixmllineinfo?view=netframework-4.5.1), it states that `IXmlLineInfo` can be found in:

> **Assemblies:** System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll, System.Xml.dll, netstandard.dll

Fortunately, `System.Xml` is in the [Supported .NET Framework Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/database-objects/supported-net-framework-libraries) list (along with `System.Xml.Linq`), so you should have no problem adding a reference to this and having it work without any problem.